# Android: How to show context menu of activity while keeping soft keyboard shown

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext, contextmenu

I would like to show the context menu of my activity while keeping the soft keyboard shown. Here is my code in creating menu for my main activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem m = menu.add(0, LOGIN_MENU_ITEM, 0, "Login");
    m.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences); 
    m = menu.add(0, CONFIGURE_MENU_ITEM, 0, R.string.menu_settings);
    m.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);
    m = menu.add(0, EXIT_MENU_ITEM, 0, R.string.menu_exit);
    m.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    m = menu.add(0, ABOUT_MENU_ITEM, 0, R.string.menu_about);
    m.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    Intent intent = null;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case ABOUT_MENU_ITEM:
        if (m_AlertDlg != null) 
        {
            m_AlertDlg.cancel();
        }

        final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.about).replace("\\n","\n").replace("${VERSION}", getVersion(this)));
        Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

        m_AlertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        //          .setMessage(getString(R.string.about).replace("\\n","\n").replace("${VERSION}", getVersion(this)))
        .setMessage(s)
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_about))
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon22_click)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .show();

        ((TextView)m_AlertDlg.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        break;

    case EXIT_MENU_ITEM: 
        on(this,false);
        //          final Boolean exit_rem = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(Settings.PREF_REMEMBER, false);
        //          if (!exit_rem){
        //              Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        //              edit.putString(Settings.PREF_USERNAME, "");
        //              edit.putString(Settings.PREF_PASSWORD, "");
        //              edit.commit();
        //          }
        Receiver.pos(true);
        Receiver.engine(this).halt();
        Receiver.mSipdroidEngine = null;
        Receiver.reRegister(0);
        stopService(new Intent(this,RegisterService.class));
        finish();
        break;

    case CONFIGURE_MENU_ITEM: 
        try {
            intent = new Intent(this, org.sparksoftsip.sipua.ui.Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
        break;

    case LOGIN_MENU_ITEM: 
        LoginScreen();
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

In my main activity, I've built a custom AutoCompleteTextView, wherein it receives focus on start. I listen to key presses here, and plans to open the context menu by listening to the menu button. However nothing is happening to my current code:

```
public class InstantAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
public InstantAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
}
private Activity getActivity() {
    Context context = getContext();
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        return (Activity) context;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean enoughToFilter() {
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event)
{
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode() && event.getAction () == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        Log.v("", "Back Pressed");
        activity.onBackPressed();

        //Want to call this method which will append text
        //init();
    }

    if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU == event.getKeyCode() && event.getAction () == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        Log.e("hello", event.toString());
        activity.openContextMenu(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
    }
    return true;
    //return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
}
}
```

I have tried using

```
openContextMenu(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content))
```

however, nothing is happening. I have also tried `(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content))` and `(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getViewRoot())`, but nothing shows up. How do I remedy this?

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools, e.g. to format the source code on this site. That will enable you to make your questions and answers more readable which is often a key factor to get good responses.

Answer (score 1):

It looks I made a foolish mistake. I did not use a context menu, but rather an options menu. So, the code for my on key press should be

```
openOptionsMenu()
```

instead of using

```
openContextMenu(View)
```